# Using result of logical tests for default values

Tags: javascript

This is more of a "experience from the trenches" question.

Given this piece of javascript

```
/**
 * @param [foo] 
 *         {Object} an optional object (it can be null, undefined, empty, etc..)
 * @param [foo.bars]
 *         {Array} an Array that *might* be in the object
 */
function (foo) {
  // I want to get the array, or an empty array in any 
  // of the odd cases (foo is null, undefined, or foo.bars is not defined)
  var bars = [];
  if (foo && foo.bars) {
     bars = foo.bars
  }
  // ....
}
```

I'm trying to shorten this ; according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) it should be ok to write :

```
function (foo) {
  var bars = (foo && foo.bars) || [];
  // ...
}
```

Am I missing a case (set of value, or other browser) where this does not work ? Is there a shorter / cleaner way to do this ?

On a more subjective node, would you consider that unreadable ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is acceptable and readable form

Comment: I agree with @jarmod. A "javascript" developer might know about using && and || this way but plenty of engineers where javascript is just one of many languages they use would probably have difficulty with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like it at all.  To a conventional programmer, it reads as if the resulting value will be true if (foo && foo.bars) evaluates to true, otherwise it will be an empty array.

I would prefer to see the following:

```
var bars = (foo && foo.bars) ? foo.bars : [];
```

Comment: While it may look to result in `true`, it might make sense to read the ES5 spec and understand operators, before using the language.

Comment: @Ian putting aside the fact that hardly *anyone* reads the spec for a language before reading code written in it ( ;) ) , I was concerned about browsers whose *implementers* did not carefully read the ES5 spec (if only, because the spec did not exist when the browser was developed..)

Comment: @Ian We have missed the boat but I wish that all languages had implemented booleans and boolean tests the same way - 5 is not a boolean, nor is ptr or empty array.  Languages should not allow "if (5)" (it should be "if (5 != 0)") or "if (ptr)" (it should be "if (ptr != NULL)".  The result of a boolean test should be an intrinsic true or false, not some other side-effect like b in (a || b || c) if a evaluates to false.  I understand the "wow, I can do more in fewer characters" appeal but I bet you that the cost to society in terms of software bugs (and perhaps crashed NASA vehicles) is huge.

Comment: @phtrivier Hey, you're absolutely right about reading the spec before using the language, my point was just that there are a lot of quirks in JavaScript (and other languages) that can always cause trouble. That's a very general statement, because I could easily take a concept (such as using `==` in JavaScript) and try to apply it to Java strings, but it wouldn't work (you need to use `.equals()`). While it's nice to stick to "normal" programming conventions, languages have powers that you should take advantage of. Then again, we need people's opinions :)

Comment: @jarmod I know, I was just being a stickler. To a new JS programmer, these types of quirks aren't apparent and *can* lead to bugs. But I hope that the people who are writing programs for NASA fully understand the language...I mean, they do some complex stuff. And trust me, I'm not one that looks for less characters in a solution...I usually prefer the more readable/understandable solution. I think your answer is a good point, so I'll upvote it. I think I just needed to think it through more

Answer (score 4):

That's a perfectly valid way to do it, so long as you know that `foo.bars` is never defined as a truthy value that isn't an array (like `foo = {bars: 1})`.

It is not unreadable, as most Javascript develops are familar with the way `&&` and `||` work and use them for assigning default values all the time.

Comment: in this case, the result would be 1 (exactly what the function caller asked), right ? Granted, that would be an error, but one on the caller's fault, so I don't think it's really a problem...